# Histogram for time periods using SQLite (regular buckets 1h wide)

Tags: sql, sqlite, histogram, unix-timestamp

I have a series of visitor data and would like to represent its timespans as a histogram the same way [Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaUx4.png) does.
[image: Google Maps]
My table has two columns: `firstSeen` and another one called `lastSeen`. Both contain (I think) so called Unix-timestamps such as `1581981627248.0` or `1581981629641.0`, their type is `REAL`.
And I'm a little bit lost I have to say, I'm not too experienced in using SQL. Calculating the average stay time and so on was easy but this is kind of weird?
I could easily do something like the following query:

```
SELECT 
    strftime('%H', datetime(round(firstseen / 1000), 'unixepoch', 'weekday 1')) as 'Hour'
FROM visitors;
```

This is already for only one day (monday), which I guess it is okay I guess.
Then I could `count` and `group by` the hour. But wouldn't this alone be wrong? I would only count `firstSeen` as a field but what about a visitor which was present at 08:59-09:00? As I understand it, you would have to count their present twice in this case, once for the time span of `08:00` to `08:59` and once for `09:00` to `09:59`. I also see another problem for empty slots, would it be possible to include these? Would that even make sense?

I hope it's clear what I'd like to accomplish and someone can point me in the right direction.

~Edit~
added MRE:

```
CREATE TABLE `detections_2` (
    `firstseen` REAL NOT NULL,
    `lastseen`  REAL NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO detections_2(
    firstSeen,
    lastSeen
)
VALUES
    (1581892607,1581892644),
    (1581892607,1581892694),
    (1581892607,1581892703),
    (1581892607,1581892629),
    (1581892607,1581892619),
    (1581892607,1581892683),
    (1581892607,1581892702),
    (1581892607,1581892651),
    (1581892607,1581892697),
    (1581892607,1581892654),
    (1581892607,1581892680),
    (1581892607,1581892619),
    (1581892607,1581892700),
    (1581892607,1581892716),
    (1581892607,1581892700),
    (1581892607,1581892643),
    (1581892607,1581892720),
    (1581892607,1581892647),
    (1581892607,1581892726),
    (1581892607,1581892679),
    (1581892607,1581892665),
    (1581892607,1581892701),
    (1581892607,1581892659),
    (1581892607,1581892725),
    (1581892607,1581892662),
    (1581892607,1581892661),
    (1581979007,1581979037),
    (1581979007,1581979054),
    (1581979007,1581979038),
    (1581979007,1581979100),
    (1581979007,1581979027),
    (1581979007,1581979080),
    (1581979007,1581979034),
    (1581979007,1581979119),
    (1581979007,1581979027),
    (1581979007,1581979093),
    (1581979007,1581979068),
    (1581979007,1581979061),
    (1581979007,1581979115),
    (1581979007,1581979126),
    (1581979007,1581979106),
    (1581979007,1581979114),
    (1581979007,1581979078),
    (1581979007,1581979078),
    (1581979007,1581979056),
    (1581979007,1581979117),
    (1581979007,1581979040),
    (1581979007,1581979057),
    (1581979007,1581979068),
    (1581979007,1581979103)
```

Comment: @Yunnosch updated with MRE :

Comment: Welcome to SO, I can see that you have many questions in this single question! - Some of those questions are *Opinion Based* and you can answer them by getting help from your *Domain Expert* not us! - And actually I can't find your main question!, Please make more focus on a single technical question else we can't help you well. -HTH ;).

Comment: And If you have problem in writing a query, we need to see a result based on your sample data -HTH

Comment: What you provided is not an MRE. Running the shown query results in `Error: no such table: visitors`.

Comment: Also please define the desired output. What values do you want to see in the sqlite result? I think you would like a list of hours (0--23) with the number of visitors which were present in at least one of the minutes of that hour. Please confirm. Ideally show the output you expect for the shown sample data.

Comment: Your sample data seems not plausible. According to it, all visitors were first detected at one of only two different times.

Comment: Judging from the result of `select rowid, lastseen-firstseen from detections_2;` all  your visitors were only present for times in subsecond range. Please provide sample data which make more sense.